# Currently executing code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm looking for way to see currently executing code. My reason is: I have ruby classes, that are been monkey patched by lots of patches, so its close to impossible to track which methods were changed. Is there any way to check what code has been loaded into memory and currently executing?

Ask for more details if you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Getting the Origin of a Method

In ruby 1.9 and newer, you can open a debugger/console at any point and ask the method for it's source location.

For example, when looking for the definition of the `admin?` method of my `User` class I can do the following:

```
user = User.first
=> #<User id: 1, ...>
user.method(:admin?).source_location
=> ["/Users/tessi/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activemodel-4.0.13/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb", 382]
```

It tells me that the `admin?` method is defined in ActiveModel in the file above and in line 382 of that file.

In a similar way you could iterate over all methods of your class and check the origin of the methods:

```
user.methods.map {|method_name| user.method(method_name).source_location}
```

### Monkey Patching

This still works with patched classes. When opening a rails console, I can edit my `User` class and look at the `source_location` again:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def admin?
    puts 'the patched admin? method'
    super
  end
end

User.first.method(:admin?).source_location
=> ["(pry)",2]
```

Now, the method's location is in my console (pry) at statement 2. This works, because my patch creates a new Method-object which replaces the old method in the method dictionary of the `User` class. The new method object returns a different `source_location`.

Comment: this is a little not what am i looking for. My methods might be changed with monkey patches, so source_location most likely will show me old unchanged code, while i want to see current runtime code

Comment: Have a look at the updated answer, please. When you patch a method, you effectively delete the old method and create a new one. In this case, you just ask the new method for it's source location. Hint: ask for the `source_location` after all patches have been applied.

Answer (score 2):

Another way besides the debugger mentioned by tessi, would be to use `ruby-prof` to benchmark the whole application and analyze the generated tree.

Every called method is in there, so the desired or not desired versions as well.